# Get caller in Array.prototype

Tags: javascript

I am doing like this

```
Array.prototype.foo = function (){
  return this.concat(this);
};

a = [1,2,3];
a.foo(); 
a; // [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

How can I define a variable inside Array.prototype.foo?
If I try somtehing like this:

```
this = this.concat(this)
```

**I get an error:**

"ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: Like always? `var aVariable = ...;`. You can never assign to `this`.

Comment: as @Felix Kling said: Array.prototype.foo = function () { var a = this.concat(this); return a; };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). To change the current object, you have to modify it by changing its properties.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function (){
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, this);
    return this;
};

a = [1,2,3];
a.foo(); 
a; // [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Your current code does `return` a new instance, which you would need to reassign to `a`.

Comment: Thanks, "Array.prototype.push.apply(this, this);" - that is what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately too few people know that `push` takes multiple arguments :-) More explicit: `for (var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++) this[l+i]=this[i];`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reassign "this". You can assigne a new value to your "a" variable though.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function (){
 return this.concat(this);
};

a = [1,2,3];
a = a.foo();
console.log(a);
```